# Как с помощью PhantomJS сделать скриншот страницы с динамическими объектами?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Пытаюсь сделать скриншот страницы с динамическими объектами js, но каждый раз получается один и тот же скриншот с одним и тем же расположением объектов.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Возможно, вы делаете скриншот сразу после загрузки страницы, не дожидаясь события, которое запускает триггер на изменение объектов?

Comment: С какими динамическими объектами? Которые подгружаются Ajaxом?